How to create a custom make:migration command in Laravel?
I want to make a new command in Laravel that creates a migrationfile and also prefills it with table definitions. I already know that the MigrationCreator uses stubs as template and populates it with a table name.
So I think I need to extend the Illuminate\Database\Migrations\MigrationCreator, override the $this->customStubPath with the path to my custom made stubs and override the populateStub method so it will not only replace the "{{ table }}" but also replace my custom tags.
I already created a command (app/Console/MyCustomMakeMigrationCommand.php) that I want to use to start the process.
The problem I'm facing is that I somehow cannot connect these two things together. This is how my code (the relevant part of app/Console/MyCustomMakeMigrationCommand.php) looks like now.
protected function writeMigration($name)
{
    $myCustomMigrationCreator = new MyCustomMigrationCreator(); // Extends Illuminate\Database\Migrations\MigrationCreator
    $file = $myCustomMigrationCreator->create($name, 'database/migrations', $table);

    $this->line("<info>Created Migration:</info> {$file}");
}

I get an error message that the constructor of the MyCustomMigrationCreator needs two parameters. I know its about the parameters $files and $customStubPath. $customStubPath is (I guess) the path to my custom stubs but I'm not sure and I have no clue what the parameter $files must look like.
My question:
Am I on the right track and if so please help me to "connect the dots" to a working code and if not so please tell me how can I solve this task?

well if you check Illuminate\Database\Migrations\MigrationCreator you can see that $files is a instance of Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem and is used to interact with the file system, like checking if migration exists, writing the file on the file system ect

remember you can use the container to resolve dependencies via the app() function

The MigrationServiceProvider calls registerCreator with return new MigrationCreator($app['files'], $app->basePath('stubs'));, just mimic the behaviour and you should be good to go, e.g. $app = app(); new MyCustomMigrationCreator($app['files'], $app->basePath('stubs')); or call parent::__construct($app['files'], $app->basePath('stubs'));
